# Python/pandas: sequence to series (transform a sequence so that each element of the series is a sum of sequence elements)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to convert a for-loop to vector calculations. I'm not sure what to do with this operation:

```
for i in np.arange(int_lookback, len(items)):
    res.ix[i] = items.ix[(i - lookback):i].diff().abs().sum()
```

'i' is the for-loop iterator.

Comment: Can you add some data sample with desired output?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to generate a full example then got the answer below which led me to coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the expected `DF`, I'm guessing you want to compute successive difference between cells, take it's absolute value and then perform the rolling summation whose window length would vary depending on the `lookback` value.

```
res = items.diff().abs().rolling(window=lookback).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it using pandas.rolling_sum(items.shift().diff().abs(), window=lookback-1). I had to use pandas.rolling_sum() because I am on old version of pandas which doesn't have ,rolling()